# How to view list of recently viewed questions?

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

Is there a way to quickly bring up recently viewed questions over a user-specified time interval?

If not, this could be a useful feature on the Account Activity page.

Comment: I assume you know how to check your **activity** under your profile. Of course it only includes posts that you voted on or reviewed/edited, and comments you left. I agree that a recently viewed list would be useful.

Comment: Why not use your browser history? You can filter it by site and sort by time in most browsers...

Comment: I found out that the browser history was not so kind to me when trying to find a question I saw an hour an ago (my memory is not so great). A history of recently viewed questions, maybe with a small preview when you hover over the question, like google does with its search, would be a great way to see the questions you have been reading for quick reference. In this way I would not have to favorite all the questions that I think might be useful only during a day.

Comment: [Relevant request on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67675). It seems like at least for now, the answer is no.